# Renaming Namespace in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my visual studio sharepoint 2010 visual web part project, while creating the project, I typed the name that I want, yet when it went to the class file for editing, the namespace code says:

```
namespace PDFLibrary.VisualWebPart1
```

The `PDFLibrary` is the name I put which is ok, but I want to rename `VisualWebPart1` if possible.

Does anyone know how to do this? Please share if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `VisualWebPart` part of the name and right click it, then select Refactor->Rename, or select that part and press Ctrl+R+R which should have the same effect.

Comment: When I try to rename `VisualWebPart1` using ctrl+r+r, I get the message: `a web part or web form control on this page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "search and replace" in entire solution. Just search all "PDFLibrary.VisualWebPart1" in your solution and replace with your new string. This is what Refacor -> Rename does as well.